# How to access buttons in a separate HTML file in the HTML file it is included in as header?

Tags: html, django

I'm making an application which requires a header that consist of navigation buttons. I need to access these buttons at the respective home screen where this header html is included in.

However, when I try to access these buttons, they won't do anything -even though I've got an if-statement which calls for all of these buttons when pressed.

I've tried separating the header.html to see if it works as a normal page -which it does. It only doesn't work when it is included as a header.

The HTML of the header:

```
<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="sidenav">
            <button type="submit" name="vergelijken" value="vergelijken">Vergelijken</button><br>
            <button type="submit" name="dag" value="dag">Dag</button><br>
            <button type="submit" name="week" value="week">Week</button><br>
            <button type="submit" name="maand" value="maand">Maand</button><br>
            <button type="submit" name="jaar" value="jaar">Jaar</button><br>
        &nbsp;
            <button type="submit" name="live" value="live">Live</button>
            {% load static %}
            <img src="{% static 'images/rdot.png' %}" class="rdot_logo"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The django code:

```
def header(request):
    global keuze
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get('vergelijken'):
            print('hallo')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/vergelijk/')
        elif request.POST.get('dag'):
            keuze = 'dag'
        elif request.POST.get('week'):
            keuze = 'week'
        elif request.POST.get('maand'):
            keuze = 'maand'
        elif request.POST.get('jaar'):
            keuze = 'jaar'
        elif request.POST.get('live'):
            keuze = 'live'
    return render(request, 'header.html')
```

I need these if statements in the django code to work in when the template is being used as an include in the base.html page. Currently the buttons and everything are visible, but not functional as an included page. However, when the page is used as a normal webpage, these buttons work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your form does not have an `action` attribute. So it will post back to the view that rendered the page, instead of to the `header` view.

You need to define a URL that points to your header view, and use `action="{% url "header"}"` to point to it.

Note also, you **must not under any circumstances** use global variables like that.

Comment: Hi Daniel! thanks for your response, however its not really what im looking for. Only 1 of those buttons (vergelijken) is a redirect to another page. the rest of the buttons are modifications for the page the header.html is included in.

Comment: I don't really understand what that means. If you want to modify the page you're on without reloading, then you need JavaScript, so your view wouldn't be involved at all.

Comment: Alright well, those buttons under "vergelijken" are suppose to change the back end data my application uses to create some graphs and heatmaps. So its suppose to refresh the page, however it wont pass anything to the header function i have in my views when i press a button in the actual page. Hopefully this makes a bit more sense.

Comment: But that view does not even render anything to do with graphs and heatmaps. It just renders the header again. So this approach doesn't seem to make sense at all. Anyway, like I say, there is no "passing to the header function"; views are called by URLs, if your form does not post to the URL associated with the header view then the view will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

Well i found out what the problem was. Apparently when you include a HTML file into another, you can call for the buttons of the foreign html file in the file it is called into. So i was trying to make a separate def for this included HTML file, turns out this wasn't necessary and could just use the def of the HTML file the foreign file is imported in.